# Power Automate, Email Flow not sending correct value

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, powerapp, microsoft-flow

I setup a flow to send an email of the value of my SharePoint list.
My Project ID is sent fine via email, but my `PMName` is not sent in a correct format.

Does anyone know why this value is not giving me the correct name?

I'm not sure what this error msg is.

**Flow**

[image]

**Email:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the display name of user in email body, use `PMName DisplayName` instead of just `PMName` from "Dynamic content" like:

[image]